# Problema con APK Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, apk, programación-móvil

Hace poco empece a incursionar en el terreno de las aplicaciones para Android, específicamente con el Android Studio.

Hice algunas aplicaciones sencillas pero me encuentro con un problema:

A la hora de exportar mi código a una APK, uso la funcion "Build APK", la cual me construye el instalador.

El problema radica en que a algunas personas que les paso esta aplicación les tira el error "No se puede instalar la aplicación".

Yo tengo un celular sony Z5 (Con android 7.0) y un Samsung J7 (Android 7.0) y lo descargue en ambos y funcionaba perfectamente, pero también lo probé en un Huawei P8 lite (android 4.1) y un motorola moto Z (Android 8.0) y me tiraba el error en instalación.

Hay alguna causa en particular, ya sea de los celulares o mi código que se pueda hacer para que funcione?

Gracias

Comment: Hola @FelipeOtero. Has revisado que no sea por la versión de Android? Cómo generas la apk, la firmas? Puedes poner tu AndroidManifest? A ver si dando algún dato más podemos dar con el error

Comment: Puede ser que uses funciones de API's posteriores a anteriores a ciertos Android y que haya incompatibilidades. Eso les pasa a todas las compañías. Por eso las actualizaciones muchas veces empiezan des de los SmartPhones más nuevos a los más viejos.

Comment: Al generar el apk, te pide que elijas con qué versión de firma quieres firmar la app, v1 o v2. Si has elegido la v2, deberías probar a elegir la v1 que es la antigua y más compatible

Answer (score 1):

La función "Build APK" suele causar este problema, lo correcto si vas a distribuir tu App es firmar el APK usando la función "Generate Signed Apk".
Aquí encuentras info sobre la firma de Apps: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es-419

Ahora como alternativa para no tener que firmar el App debes saber que
el problema con el "Build APK" es causado por el Instant Run de Android Studio así que lo puedes deshabilitar en File>Settings y una vez deshabilitado volver a probar con el "Build Apk", pero como dije antes si ya estás distribuyendo tu App lo mejor es firmarlo.

Aquí como deshabilitar el Instant Run
[image: Deshabilitar Instant Run]

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la respuesta. En cuanto pueda solucionar este problema (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194922/android-studio-google-preconditions) voy a intentar probar tu solución.