# Android Studio Google preconditions

Tags: java, class, apk

Estoy empezando en Android studio haciendo aplicaciones pequeñas y probando cosas nuevas.
Hasta anoche, Android Studio funcionaba correctamente y no me presentaba problema, pero hoy, al encender mi computadora y querer abrir mi proyecto me muestra el siguiente error:

> Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions'.

Ya probé reinstalando Android Studio y haciendo lo siguiente:

- `Clean project y Build project` (Sin resultado alguno, sigue mostrando el mismo error)
- Mirar si estoy trabajando en modo offline (Sin resultado, ya que la casilla de "Offline work" estaba desactivada
- Invalidate Cache/Restar (No hizo nada, sigue el problema)

  - Al eliminar la carpeta ./gradle , no se vuelve a descargar automáticamente ni tocando la opción "Re-Download dependencies and sync projects"

No se como resolverlo, busque en foros y demás pero no consigo resultado y no conozco la causa de este problema si hace un par de horas funcionaba todo bien y no hubo cambios en mi computadora

Saludos

Comment: Saludos @Felipe, bienvenido a stackoverflow, puedes eliminar la carpeta `.gradle` en el directorio de tu usuario, lo que deberia hacer que los archivos de `.gradle` vuelvan a descargarse e instalarse, tambien prueba con la opcion en File, `Invalidate Caches/Restart.`

Comment: @DavidVillegas Ya probé con eliminar la carpeta .gradle y no se descarga nada, por el contrario, cuando toco la opcion "Re-Download dependencies and sync projects" no hace nada y la carpeta de Gradle sigue sin bajarse.

Por otro lado, hice lo de "Invalidate Caches/Restart" y no dio solución, sigue con el mismo problema

Comment: que error te muestra el log de Android studio?

Comment: Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'  

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions  

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Preconditions  

Estos son los "Títulos" del log de android studio en donde hay error. (Tuve que suprimir las lineas donde se encuentran los errores por el cap de caracteres)

Answer (score 0):

Elimine los directorios .gradle tanto en su directorio personal como en el nivel superior de su proyecto. Las direcciones de caché de Gradle no se ven afectadas por la opción "Clear caches and restart".

Luego Build>Clean Project

Comment: Buenas: yo tengo mi carpeta .gradle guardada en mi directorio de Android.

Ademas de esa, cual debería eliminar ?